# Sharepoint Site Collection "Send To" functionality not fully passed in template

Tags: sharepoint, templates

I have a Sharepoint Site Collection and I've created a site which I want to be the template for all sites created within this collection.

In the site template, I have added "Send To" functionality that will allow the user to send the documents to a Master site.

This all works fine, but when I create another site using the template, the "Send To" option is there, but instead of the Master Site option, it says "Other location".

Why is the "Send To" location being removed when any new sites are created?  Is there a way to override this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Mark.

Comment: @Mark Kadlec: Can you please edit your question with how the "Send To" functionality was added? Is it a feature using the ECB? Are you able to include any small snippets of relevant code?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  Actually, it was created really easy - no code.  In the site (before making it a temmplate), in the document lib I clicked on:

>Settings >Document Library Settings >Advanced Settings

In the "Custom Send and Destination" section I put the Destination name and URL.  That's the one that keeps disappearing when the template is used.